# Div float keep fixed and 100% height of the viewport

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a basic responsive structure for a website with CSS. So far I have managed to make three column divs, a menu, a sidebar and one for content.

What I would like to achieve now is to have the menu and the sidebar to be 100% of the viewport height and *fixed* so that the content div is "scrollable" but the menu and the sidebar stays on top no matter how much content there is in the `col content` column. Naturally, I do not want this to happen in the media query though.

How can I achieve this most efficiently with CSS. Do I have to restructure the divs in HTML or is there any way to achieve this with CSS?

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */

.section {
  clear: both;
}
/*  COLUMN SETUP  */

.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
/*  GRID OF THREE  */

.menu {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #98D2ED
}
.sidebar {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #D3ADAD
}
.content {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #C9E4D1
}
/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="col menu">
    <p>
      Menu
    </p>
    I want this cloumn to be fixed and full height of the viewport when the screen size is above 480px.
  </div>
  <div class="col sidebar">
    <p>
      Sidebar
    </p>
    I want this cloumn to be fixed and full height of the viewport when the screen size is above 480px.
  </div>
  <div class="col content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `height:100vh`? the vh unit means % of viewport height. It is pretty well supported on newer browsers (other than IE of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox, either for known/unknown width and height elements, The key is to set the content area to `overflow:auto`, and switch the `flex-direction` to `column` in media queries.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvfdpsum/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.menu    { background: grey;   }
.sidebar { background: silver; }

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<div class="content">
  <!-- scroll test -->
  <div style="height:1000px;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Or, the traditional way to set the menu and sidebar to `position:fixed`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbL8eoug/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
.menu, .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.menu {
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
.sidebar {
  left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: silver;
}
.content {
  overflow: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    margin: 100px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu, .sidebar {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .sidebar {
    top: 50px;
  }
  .content {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<div class="content">
  <!-- scroll test -->
  <div style="height:1000px;">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. It seems more intuitive to go for the flexbox solution, although I am a little worried about browser support. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want your `.menu` and `.sidebar` to be stuck to the screen in one place and have the content be scrollable. And add some more code to other things as well, I know that sounds vague, but it would be a waste of time to write everything down, as I have edited you I finished copy, and I have notes that explain all my changes (and the reasons for doing so) in the code below.

I removed the `float`s and their `class`es, as I believe those are not necessary, and that the `float`s do more harm than good. As well as moved the `.content` to be in the middle column (between `.menu` and `.sidebar`). However, if you need to, feel free to change any or al of these things back.

---

Here's the updated code: (and here's a JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unk7ds0v/))

I know that `.menu` has a weird space above it (when running the snippet and the JSFiddle), but I have it live on my website [here](http://jeffarries.com/tests/test3), and it behaves perfectly fine, and uses the same code.

```css
* {
 margin: 0px; /* Added to remove margin from everything */
 padding: 0px; /* Added to remove margin from everything */
}

.section, .menu, .sidebar, .content {
 display:inline-block !important; /* Added so they will line up next to each other */
}

.section {width:100%;} /* Pretty self explanatory, added to set ".section" to a width of 100% */

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.menu {
 width: 33%; /* Was already here */
 background-color: #98D2ED; /* Was already here */
 
 height:100vh; /* Makes it be 100% of the Viewport Height, or 100% of the browser window height */
 
 position: fixed; /* Makes it stay "fixed" to one place on the screen */
}

.sidebar {
 width: 33%; /* Was already here */
 background-color: #D3ADAD; /* Was already here */
 position:absolute; top:0px; left: 67%; /* To make the element in the right place, add the width of "menu" and "content" */

 height:100vh; /* Makes it be 100% of the Viewport Height, or 100% of the browser window height */

 position: fixed; /* Makes it stay "fixed" to one place on the screen */
}
.content {
 width: 34%; /* Was already here, but changed it to 34 to make the website fill the page */
 background-color: #C9E4D1; /* Was already here */

 position:absolute; top:0px; left:33%; /* To make the element in the right place, make this the width of "menu" */
}


/* The CSS below this was already here */

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu { width: 100%; }
  .sidebar { width: 100%; }
  .content { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class="section">
    <div class="menu">
        Menu
    </div>
 <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

Really Hope that helped!

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with the question, sorry. The code you have provided defeats the purpose of making responsive code and it does not have the structure I explained.

Comment: @Arete I understand, but you can't use any of it?  Do you want me to take my post down?

Comment: @Arete Upon looking at your question further, I see now the structure and responsiveness you are wanting, was that there before? If it was I didn't see it, sorry!  I see you have an answer that works for you, so I won't try anything more.  P.S. Do you want me to take my post down?